# git is not tracking .gitignore but .gitignore itself is working locally

Tags: git, github

I have a .gitignore file in my project that is working fine with local git repo. When I pushed up the project, somehow the .gitignore file did not get pushed up to the remote branch. When I edit the local .gitignore file, so let's say I comment ".gradle" in it and do `git status`, git recognizes this change and shows me that the .gradle folder is untracked. I read through questions related to .gitignore and tried the `git rm --cached .gitignore`, I got this -

> fatal: pathspec '.gitignore' did not match any files

...and made no difference. What is going on here? I have pushed several new projects to remote branches before and this is the first time the .gitignore file is not being tracked by git.

**Updated (1/19):**
I tried `git add .gitignore` and got this -

> The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
>   .gitignore

I checked the .gitignore file to make sure it does not have any paths that cause this file to be ignored. I remembered reading about a global .gitignore file...so I looked for that and found a file ~/.gitignore_global which had .gitignore in it! I commented that out and now git is able to track the file. I am not sure how this file got into the global .gitignore.

Comment: Git can totally use the local file, even if it doesn't track it for source control. To track it, run `git add .gitignore`, unless `.gitignore` is in `.gitignore`. Due to how shell expansion works, `git add *` will not add a dot-file. `git rm` does not work if the file isn't tracked by git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `.gitignore` file is like any other file. In order to have it tracked by Git, you will need to add it using `git add` so that Git starts tracking it. The fact that Git internally uses it to construct the list of files to ignore has nothing to do with it.

Since you tried to remove it using `git rm`, and Git told you that *“'`.gitignore`' did not match any files”*, this is a clear sign that the `.gitignore` file was never added to the index.

So add the file and commit it, in order to start tracking it:

```
git add .gitignore
git commit
```

Comment: Given that the OP has run `git status` and hasn't mentioned seeing `.gitignore` in there, I think it's likely that `.gitignore` is itself in `.gitignore` (as Alexander Huszagh also offered as a possibility in a comment on the question). In that case, `git add .gitignore` won't work until the file is edited to no longer exclude itself (or `-f` is used, but that'd be silly here)

Comment: I updated my question...it was the global gitignore file...still a mystery why this file got that entry...I have not changed anything and have pushed new projects in the past with the .gitignore file successfully. I will mark yours as the right answer though...because it led me to the fix!

Comment: The global ignore file was likely changed after those projects had added their gitignore. Projects that already have files tracked will not be affected by a new ignore rule.